# Is this gash on my tire a significant damage that warrants a replacement?

Tags: sidewall-damage

Possibly from my recent encounter with a curb I noticed a gash on one of my tires.

It looks like a slice. I wanted to use a glue to keep it in place.

Picture is attached.

[image: Image 1]

Here are more images as requested.

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

---

Here are more images as requested.[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Need to see more, how deep? can you see the plies? If you can then replace it.

Comment: Yeah, if you can see the fibres that give the tire strength it should be replaced.

Comment: I have edited your additional pictures into the question

Answer (score 1):

Are the plies exposed?

[image]

If so, this tyre is clearly damaged and is now weaker in this area.

It is now far more probable that tyre will blow out when driven at fast speeds over an uneven surface, such as road derbis or a pothole.

Were I in your situation, I would without a doubt change this tyre as a matter of priority.

The loss of the price of a tyre is small and bounded.

The loss of your life, the life of your passengers, and the life of other road users or pedesterians is priceless.

Comment: im not sure if plies are exposed. is what you see in the pictures look like plies?

Comment: See this image for an example of exposed plies. If you see any plies, change the tyre: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-yQlzjiykWbg/VkRqqSQz8PI/AAAAAAAAACs/CMLUjr8cYJo/s1600/IMG_7776.JPG